# django 1.6.1, Form, Is there a elegant way to render old data and edit old data from a model?

Tags: django

I have an 'accounts' app which contains a custom `User` model, a `Profile` model that holds OneToOneField to `User`. When an user instance is created, the relevant profile instance is automatically created, too.

Now I design a page which contains a form for editing three fileds of profile for an existing user. When a user request a url like 'accounts/profile_edit/1/', if the request user is legal, I get his old profile data of the three fields first, then response an edit page with the old data as the initial value of the form.

My current solution works fine, but I think it is not elegant, maybe contains some unnecessary waste of database querying. Mainly two ways:

The way I get old profile data as the initial value for the profile edit form.

The way I save edit data for an existing profile.

So if someone could give me any advice , it will be apreciated.

The urls.py, views.py, models.py and forms.py fiels are:

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('accounts.views',
#...
    url(r'^profile_edit/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$',
        'profile_edit',
        {'template_name': 'accounts/profile_edit.html'},
        name='profile_edit'), 
#...
)


#views.py
def profile_edit(request,
    template_name, 
    user_id,
    edit_form=ProfileForm,):

    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:login'),
        )

    #ensure the request user is the edit user
    if request.user.pk!=int(user_id):
        raise Http404

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = edit_form(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.edit(profile=request.user.profile)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:profile',kwargs={'user_id':user_id}))
    else:
        #render old profile data, also seems not elegant...how to solve it?
        profile = request.user.profile
        old_profile={'location':profile.location,
        'description':profile.description,
        'signature':profile.signature,
        }   
        form = edit_form(data=old_profile)
    context = {
    'form': form,
    }
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,)

#models.py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    #lots of definations here...not related to this question

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)  
    location = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True)  
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True) 
    signature = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True) 

#forms.py
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['location', 'description', 'signature'] 

    #this is not elegant..how to solve it?
    def edit(self,profile):
        profile.location = self.cleaned_data['location']
        profile.description = self.cleaned_data['description']
        profile.signature = self.cleaned_data['signature']
        profile.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass [`instance`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) parameter while instantiating the form. In that case you don't have to create dict to populate form, or iterate over field to save them.

Your view can be changed as

```
def profile_edit(request,
    template_name, 
    user_id,
    edit_form=ProfileForm,):

    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:login'),
        )

    #ensure the request user is the edit user
    if request.user.pk!=int(user_id):
        raise Http404

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = edit_form(data=request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            #no need for edit method
            updated_profile = form.save() 
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:profile',kwargs={'user_id':user_id}))
    else:
        #no need to crate dict
        form = edit_form(instance=request.user.profile)
        context = {
          'form': form,
         }
        return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. For other watchers, there seems to be a typo : `updated_profile = edit_form.save()` should be `updated_profile = form.save()` .